# error in javascript toggle class

Tags: javascript, html, class, toggle

I have this code for [toggling class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) using pure JavaScript that I found online and it is not working when I am using it in an offline website
my code is -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function classToggle() {
    this.classList.toggle('class1');
    this.classList.toggle('class2');
}
document.querySelector('#div').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.class1 {
    color: #f00;
}

.class2 {
    color: #00f;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div" class="class1">click here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Move the script below the div you are looking for in the source code.

Comment: thank you this worked! 
now i would like to add transition to it can you suggest any suitable though i know it will be a line code 
something of this sort -
.something.style.cssText ="-webkit-transition:0.6s ease-in-out;";

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the event handler after the div has rendered - for example in the onload event

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/XB63S/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function classToggle() {
  if (!this.classList) return; // no support
  this.classList.toggle('class1');
  this.classList.toggle('class2');
}
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('div').onclick=classToggle;
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.class1 {
    color: #f00;
}

.class2 {
    color: #00f;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div" class="class1">click here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.class1 {
    color: #f00;
}
.class2 {
    color: #00f;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div" class="class1">click here</div>
<script>
function classToggle() {
    this.classList.toggle('class1');
    this.classList.toggle('class2');
}
document.querySelector('#div').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate the dom before it is ready.

So either load the script that adds the handler at the end of the body tag, or use the DOMContentLoaded event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/mcgraw/pen/dYPqaJ)

```
//vanilla js -- toggle active class 
// el = object containing the elements to toggle active class and the parent  element 
var el = {
  one: document.getElementById('one'),
  two: document.getElementById('two'),
  three: document.getElementById('three'),
  hold: document.getElementById('hold')
};

 // func = object containing the logic 
 var func = {
     toggleActive: function(ele) {
     ele = event.target;
     var hold = el.hold.children;
     var huh = el.hold.children.length;
     var hasActive = ele.classList.contains('active');
     for (i = 0; i < huh; i++) {
         if (hold[i].classList.contains('active')) {
            hold[i].classList.remove('active');
         }  
     }
     if (!hasActive) {
         ele.classList.add('active');
     }
   }
 };

 //add listeners when the window loads 
 window.onload = function() {
    var holdLen = el.hold.children.length;
    for (i = 0; i < holdLen; i++) {
        el.hold.children[i].addEventListener("click", func.toggleActive);
    }

 };
```